# Convert s3.getObject response to a File object

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have a simple api that returns response from S3.getObject in the following format from the code `await this.s3.getObject(listParams).promise()`

[image: S3.getObject response]

How do i convert this to javascript [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object?

Doing something as `new File([response] as ArrayBuffer, 'test.png')` doesn't seem to work. What's the correct way to convert this?

Answer (score 2):

This was solved as follows

`new File([new Uint8Array(response.Body.data) as ArrayBufferView], 'test.png')`